# Calculate time between different milestones within a project in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have gained some initial experience in PowerBi, especially with DAX, but I am reaching my limits with the following problem. The tables below show a snippet of the dataset.

---

**
Initial situation:** There is a table (lets call it table_1) with different projects and companies that work on those projects. Each project has a unique project number. There are a lot of different projects and companies. Each company can have multiple projects.

| ProjectID | Project | Company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p325235235 | Project A | Company A |
| p575895843 | Project B | Company A |
| p578457444 | Project C | Company B |

In a second table (table_2) there are project milestones and the date on which they were reached. There are many milestones.

| ProjectID | Milestone | Milestone_reached |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p325235235 | Milestone 1 | 02.07.2024 |
| p325235235 | Milestone 2 | 02.14.2024 |
| p578457444 | Milestone 1 | 01.04.2024 |
| p575895843 | Milestone 1 | 02.09.2024 |
| p578457444 | Milestone 2 | 01.10.2024 |
| p325235235 | Milestone 3 | 02.18.2024 |

---

The aim is to calculate the time between selected milestones within a project and display it in additional columns in the first table.

| ProjectID | Project | Company | Milestone1_2 | Milestone2_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p325235235 | Project A | Company A | 7 | 4 |
| p575895843 | Project B | Company A |  |  |
| p578457444 | Project C | Company B | 6 |  |

Two further challenges: Some projects may not have reached a milestone yet. In this case, it should be left blank. It is possible that in some projects the same milestone occurs several times but with different dates - in this case, the latest date should be used for the calculation (if that's even possible).

---

My guess is that you can link it all together with the project ID, but I have no idea how to tell PowerBi to calculate the time between chosen milestones for each project, preferably in DAX.

If you've got the time, a short explanation of the code would be great as well, as I'm trying to understand and learn.

Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: What is the end goal/visualization of this? Working with Columns in DAX is much harder than with Rows. Since there can be many milestones, add these to table_1 is not a good idea. Perhaps adding it as a column to table_2 would make more sense. Or a Measure could do the same, but it depends on what visualization you are needing to do.

Comment: Thank you for your input so far!

The aim would be to be able to say how long a company takes on average to complete a particular milestone. For example, Company A has 100 projects and takes an average of 12 days to complete milestone 2 (from the date of milestone 1). The visualisation could be either a table or a graph, I have no preference at this stage. The idea of adding it to Table 1 would be to have each project with the correct company and time between milestones on the same row. However, if adding it to table 2 is more efficient, I would not mind that either.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are the Milestones always named like that in the example above (`Milestone X`)? Is there a project start date and end date?

Comment: No, the milestones have more complex names (e.g. Project Submitted, Structure Built, Payment Received, Project Finished) - I was thinking that if you use word filters, I could change them to the correct names later. Also Start Date and End Date are milestones. Thank you!